# mysql: show truncated or modified data announced by warning

Tags: mysql, verify, truncated

When INSERTing into a MYSQL table, I sometimes get a "Data truncated for column 'x' at row n" message and I'm unable to identify the data that was truncated or the resulting truncated value.  I tried to use the column/row number but this didn't lead me to any truncated value.

Is my only option to verify the data insertion by selecting it from the target table and comparing it to the source data?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found that the method you describe is the only way to figure out what data were truncated. Have you found anything better in the ensuing years?

Answer (score 0):

Your inserted data surpassed the maximum value for a given column type.If its from another table alter your destination table SCHEMA to be identical with the source table SCHEMA(at least for the columns which exist in both tables) and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I don't want to change the table; in these cases the data source (which is not usually a db table) is the problem.  I can examine the data to verify that it will fit or not, but that seems like a lot of overhead.  It would be better if mysql could reflect the errant data back to me -- since it went to the trouble to truncate it.